# I have Internet connection... but not quite?

Tags: networking, router, internet, connection

Sorry for the confusing title, but I am really confused with this problem.

Basically - I have Internet connection (and quite a solid one, not like gprs in the middle of tundra) and I can browse Internet no problem, BUT things like:

- some installers (eg. Dropbox installer)
- my company VPN connection
- Windows update
- Uplay update service (Steam works fine)

etc will refuse to work because of no connection. It happens both on LAN and WLAN. So I'm thinking "blocked ports" - but how? I turned Windows firewall off and the only other security software is Microsoft Security Essentials. So, maybe router? But thats unlikely too, as I have another computer connected to the same network, and I don't think there are any device-specific settings, and these things work okay there. Both computers are Windows 7, I don't think I ever fiddled with their network settings too much - but clearly I'm missing something here.

I'm posting here because it is really driving me nuts and I have no idea what else to try, so getting even a small clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: By "refuse" to work, what exactly happens when you try these things?  Have you tried changing DNS servers?  Have you checked the problematic computer's HOSTS file for unexpected/related entries?

Comment: So, installers tend to claim that there is no connection, trying to connect with VPN causes an error with code "0x80090305", Windows update says "80072F8F" and Uplay throws an "unrecoverable error" at me.

Comment: An yes, I googled the "80072F8F" error and seems there is nothing wrong with my system time because a) its the same as on my wrist watch, b) the web time sync setting is on. Also, my "hosts" file is empty (excluding any default comments).

Comment: Ok, good, the time appears right, but have you ensured you have the correct time-zone (and DST setting) set as well? Both the 0x80072F8F and 0x80090305 are security errors, which can be (and are most often) caused by incorrect clock settings.   Beyond that: Have you performed an `sfc /scannow` yet?  Did it report/fix any errors?  Are there any related errors reported in your Event logs?

Comment: What version of 7 is it? Is a cooperate image, could be a GPO issue? What type of internet connection is it, Cable or DSL? Have you tired to connect the computer directly to the modem? If it works could be a router issue. Try adding your PC's MAC address to the DMZ list on the router.

Comment: The date/time settings along with time zone and DMT are without a doubt correct and exactly the same as on the other computer.  sfc /scannow complains about some damaged files and that it cannot fix some of them, but how does that help me? Also tried changing DNS from default to google public ones with no result as well.

Comment: "sfc /scannow complains about some damaged files and that it cannot fix some of them, but how does that help me?"  It tells you that you have corrupted system files, and that it couldn't repair them (so they're still corrupted).  A corrupted system file could also easily cause these problems as well. Easiest way to deal with WinSxS corruption on Windows 7 is to reinstall Windows...

Comment: The hard way is to use the CBS.log file to identify which files are bad in the WinSxS store, replace them with good copies (from your other machine) and then run `SFC /scannow` repeatedly until it reports there are no more errors.

Comment: Win7 Pro 64-bit. I believe that the exact same copy is installed on both computers, the only difference being that one was not updated since july (yeah, I was quite patient) because of this problem. Setting the DMZ does not help. I have a DSL connection and it would be a bit fiddly to connect the PC directly to the line, but I will certainly try that when I get desperate enough.

Comment: You wont be able to connect directly to a DSL line with your PC. If its just this PC that has issues then its corruption like Techie says. Clean install is the best route.